# Ubuntu networking - DNS/DHCP

Tags: 13.04, dns, dhcp

How to configure Ubuntu 13.04 as my DNS (Domain Name Server) and DHCP server for other Linux client machines?

Master server ip configuration-
ip address: 192.168.200.100
gateway: 192.168.200.1
name:  ubuntu-1 (for instance)

Answer (score 1):

That is not something to be answered in one post. The `dhcpcd` package will install a DHCP server, which can be configured in the file `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf`. A basic config looks like this (make sure you fill in the correct IP addresses):

```
# Configuration for my LAN
subnet 192.168.200.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
   option domain-name-servers 192.168.200.100;
   option routers 192.168.200.1;
   option ntp-servers 192.168.200.100;
   option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
   option broadcast-address 192.168.200.255;
   range 192.168.200.101 192.168.200.200;
}
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server for more info.

A well-known DNS server is `bind`, which is available in the `bind9` package. Its configuration is done in `/etc/bind/named.conf` and `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`. In its simplest (DNS forwarding form) the latter file looks like this:

```
options {
directory "/var/cache/bind";
     forwarders {
          // list the IPs of your ISP's DNS servers here
          xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; 
          yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy;
     }
 }
```

If you want bind to act as DNS server for your own domain name, configuration gets more complicated.
See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto for more info.

Also note that the above configuration is for IPv4. For IPv6 you likely needs some additional settings.

Alternatively the `dnsmasq` package provides a simple DHCP and DNS server, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq.